# Ajax Call using YUI 3.2 in portlet 

Tags: ajax, yui, liferay, portlet

I want to implement Ajax call in liferay portlet to refresh whole portlet after some interval Is there any way to implement ajax call in yui 3.2?

Please share your ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay comes bundled with AUI an extension to YUI and has some components that maybe beneficial to you.

```
<div id="myContainer">
    // My Content
</div>
```

Say you have the above HTML, you can use the following script in your Liferay portlet to achieve what you are asking...

```
<script>
    AUI().use('aui-io', function(A) {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                var container = A.one('#myContainer').plug(
                    A.Plugin.IO,
                    {
                        uri: 'http://myurl'
                    }
                );

                container.io.start();
            },
            100000
        );
    });
</script>
```

You can see the full documentation here: http://alloy.liferay.com/deploy/api/A.Plugin.IO.html

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,this will be really helpful

Comment: Hey Mayur, I've updated the answer with the link to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks aging for sharing that doc

Comment: @RP.Hii, I want to do IPC with Ajax. Can you please help me that how can i achieve this? I have successfully done with normal IPC without Ajax but now I want to add Ajax in that....